# How can I negate a glob in vim?

Tags: vim, glob

I am trying to populate the vim arglist with all filenames in a directory that do not include "matcher".  I can populate it with filenames that DO include "matcher" using

```
args *matcher*
```

Is there a simple way to negate the glob to get all the files that don't match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I know is as follows:

```
:args * | silent! argdelete *matcher*
```

The `silent!` part is needed to omit `No match` error.

**Update.**
One can also create a handy command to type less keys:

```
:command! -nargs=* Args args * | silent! argdelete <args>
```

And use it like this:

```
:Args *matcher*
```

Comment: Nice, I'll use that. (Also, get weighted keys :) Much nicer to work with. In other words, nice gravatar)

Comment: Good solution, too bad vim doesn't support this directly.

Answer (score 1):

xaizek's command is short and clever; unfortunately, it only deals with argument files from the current directory. I've expanded on that to work with any directory, and bundle this with other helpful commands for argument handling in my [ArgsAndMore plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4152).